# Warning C4013: undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c

I got another warning which is

> C4047: 'initializing' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'.

Why do I get those warnings? I have read on MSDN that it generated if I wrote a different function name to that I wrote in the header file or it should be extern function.
Could someone shed some light on it?

My relevant code is:

**GetSignature.c**

```
#include "Parse_Database.h"
#include "Alloc_Mem.h"
#include "Get_Signature.h"


int Get_Signature(const char *filename) {
    char *database = AllocMem(filename);
    int error=0;

    //ParseDatabase(database);

    return 1;
}
```

**AllocMem**

```
#include "Alloc_Mem.h"


char *AllocMem(const char *filename)    {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int ch = EOF;
    char *buf = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    unsigned int size=0, index=0;

    /*
        Mallicous use of fopen(anyone could replace filename with a malicous modified file)
    */
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open the signature database");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(ch)   {
        fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);

        if(ch == EOF)   {
            ch = 0;
        }

        if(size <= index)   {
            size+=chunk;
            tmp = realloc(buf, size);
            if(!tmp)    {
                free(buf);
                buf = NULL;
                break;
            }
            buf = tmp;
        }

        buf[index++] = ch;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return buf;
}
```

**Alloc_Mem.h**

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
#define HEADERFILE_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#define chunk 255

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *AllocMem(const char *);

#endif
```

Comment: also, make sure you have added `#include <stdlib.h>` for the `exit()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this shall resolve your problem: replace these lines:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
#define HEADERFILE_H
```

with

```
#ifndef _ALLOC_MEM_H
#define _ALLOC_MEM_H
```

Reason: header guards shall be unique for each header file, or there would be corruption when including multiple header files. (And I guess you're using the same name in all your header files.)

**EDITED:** Also in other of your headers (`Parse_Database.h` and `Get_Signature.h`) you shall replace the header guards with different names.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know the exact line where the error is happening.  I am assuming it is

```
char *database = AllocMem(filename);
```

in `GetSignature.c`.

Generally, this error comes about because the C compiler does not have the declaration of a function when it is called (what function that is depends upon the line mentioned in the error message).  When this occurs, the C compiler assumes that the function returns `int`.

Do you have the include guard:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H
#define HEADERFILE_H
```

In `Parse_Database.h` as well?  If so, it is blocking the declaration of `AllocMem` from being included because `HEADERFILE_H` is already defined.

The usual custom is to name the defined macro the same as the header file.  For example:

```
#ifndef ALLOC_MEM_H
#define ALLOC_MEM_H
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @starrify.  I'll use backticks in the future.